# python regex "SNPEFF_AMINO_ACID_CHANGE=p.Pro3Pro/c.9T>C" extract values for the keys

Tags: python, regex, string, pattern-matching

I have few data lines

> ReadPosRankSum=###    SNPEFF_AMINO_ACID_CHANGE=p.Pro3Pro/c.9T>C   SNPEFF_CODON_CHANGE=ccT/ccC
>
> ReadPosRankSum=###    SNPEFF_AMINO_ACID_CHANGE=p.Trp7Ser/c.20G>C  SNPEFF_CODON_CHANGE=tGg/tCg
>
> ReadPosRankSum=###    SNPEFF_AMINO_ACID_CHANGE=p.Lys17Arg/c.50A>G SNPEFF_CODON_CHANGE=aAa/aGa

and so on..
I want to be able to extract just the values for the keys SNPEFF_AMINO_ACID_CHANGE, that is p.Pro3Pro/c.9T>C, p.Trp7Ser/c.20G>C and p.Lys17Arg/c.50A>G. Any ideas on how to create a pattern for this?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: `re.findall([SNPEFF_AMINI_ACID=]{1,})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when questions like this are asked some effort needs to be shown. So please take consideration to state the exact problem with at **least some effort** on what you have attempted next time.

To get you started, you could try the following regular expression:

```
>>> re.findall(r'SNPEFF_AMINO_ACID_CHANGE=(\S+)', text)
```

This will extract the values from the pattern and store them in a list.

**Explanation**:

```
SNPEFF_AMINO_ACID_CHANGE=   # match 'SNPEFF_AMINO_ACID_CHANGE='
(                           # group and capture to \1:
  \S+                       #   non-whitespace (1 or more times)
)                           # end of \1
```

[Working Demo](https://eval.in/172729)

Comment: Thank You and will post my effort from next.I was trying `re.findall([SNPEFF_AMINI_ACID=]{1,})` and that picked up all the text next to it as single alphabets and not as a word.